# how do I make a scrollable List of entry widgets in gtksharp?

Tags: c#, gtk#, scrollable

I'm trying to make a scrollable list of entry widgets, because I have an unknown number of entry widgets, and don't want them to go off the window, I've tried a few things, like a ScrolledWindow, which I think can only contain one object, so I tried using a Vbox container, which just resulted in a black box with the entry widgets in, but it just packed the entry widgets closer together as I added more instead of keeping them spaced apart but letting me scroll through them, I tried a TreeView, which just resulted in a blank box with none of the widgets showing, and I made a scrollbar, but I have no idea how I even make the scrollbar do anything, does anyone know how I can make it work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think there should be a way with the VBox inside the ScrolledWindow to do this, playing with the Height/Width Requests, Expand, Vexpand, Hexpand, Margins, Valign and Halign. You may need to set the Box height request as larger than the ScrolledWindow. Also -- I'd use a Box (Orientation = Vertical) rather than a VBox if you can.